# Usability testing vs UX testing.What is the difference?

Tags: manual-testing, quality-assurance

I khow that UX - How user feels about using a product. UI-how easy it is to use a product and how convenient is a product to end user.
Is it the same or not?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ? This might be a better question for that community.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/is-ux-the-same-as-usability

Answer (score 5):

UX (User Experience) is the process of creating and building software products (web/app/etc) that provide relevant experiences to users. It includes aspects of branding, design (UI), **usability** and function. In simple, **usuability** is subset of UX.

So when you do **Usability testing**, it's only checking if product is easy to use with real users.

For **UX testing**, you must care more aspects such as pleasure of real users, efficiency of functions, GUI, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the best user interface in the world but if the application is slow or does not solve the customers "pain" it won't be used.

User interface is one  component of user experience.

UX > UI.

Answer (score 1):

Both the term generally confuse the testers in software testing company. Usability testing is a part of User experience testing. Usability testing is being performed to determine system's ease of access by user.

User experience testing is being performed to test different aspects of user experience to determine the best way for a system and its elements to interact with its audience.

For example, let say any page having some action controls and inputs fields:-
Usability testing determine that all the controls are meaningful to end user while using the application.
User experience majorly focus on look and feel of the app. Making sure UI content, color,icons, images used in the system are aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

Usability Testing is an aspect of UX testing since User Experience Testing is a broader term. Going by the definition, Usability testing is a technique where the prototype or the product developed is taken to the users to check the quality of interaction in real-time.

On the other hand, User Experience testing is all about sticking to a documented list of features, functionalities, and navigation in order to ensure that a pleasing user experience could be offered to the end-user when the software or application is launched to the market.